# Query a DataSet

Tags: c#, xsd, datatable, dataset

I'm reading data from XML files into a strong typed `DataSet`.  The data ends up in multiple tables; can I run queries against it to create a denormalized view to display in a `DataGrid`?

Sample input:

```xml
<PeopleFile>
    <address>
        <street>123 Some Street</street>
        <town>Anytown</town>
        <resident>
            <first>Jane</first>
            <last>Doe</last>
        </resident>
        <resident>
            <first>John</first>
            <last>Doe</last>
        </resident>
    </address>
    <address>
        <street>456 Tree Street</street>
        <town>Westwood</town>
        <resident>
            <first>Mary</first>
            <last>Jones-Smith</last>
        </resident>
        <resident>
            <first>Mike</first>
            <last>Smith</last>
        </resident>
        <resident>
            <first>Kate</first>
            <last>Smith</last>
        </resident>
    </address>
</PeopleFile>
```

Desired output:

```
123 Some Street Anytown     Jane    Doe  
123 Some Street Anytown     John    Doe  
456 Tree Street Westwood    Mary    Jones-Smith  
456 Tree Street Westwood    Mike    Smith  
456 Tree Street Westwood    Kate    Smith
```

EDIT:  I should add that in addition to multiple tables per file, my real data is also split among multiple files which AFAIK will require being loaded into separate `DataSets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use Linq. There is a special set of extensions called Linq-to-Datasets.

You will need .NET 3.5 obviously, and add `using System.Data;`

If your multiple files follow the same schema you should be able to read them into separate instances of the TypedDataSet and `Merge()` those instances.

Comment: The files follow several different schemas, so at a minimum Merge()ing won't work.

Comment: There is also a Merge() at the Table level. But you will need to elaborate a bit on the Dataset(s), eg do the tables have Id's etc.

Comment: Yes.  My app was originally written using XmlSerialization and all the distinct objects had key values whose uniqueness needed to be maintained in code.  Getting away from that is a significant part of why I'm trying to change over to read into DataSets instead.  The DataSet representation broke some objects into multiple tables (eg where an A contained an array of B's); in these cases the keys were manually created.

Comment: A single file will contain what was originally a single array of objects of a single type + misc file header data.

Comment: Can I get the DataSet's into a graphical query designer?  I've never used linq before, and have always struggled to write non trivial sql by hand.

Comment: Better work some details in the question (or a new one). This trail of comments is going nowhere.