# Combine Data from multiple DataSets

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I'm loading data from multiple xml files with different schemas into DataSets.  I do have foreign key style relationships between the tables in each xml file but to date they're only enforced by code.  I need to access data coming from multiple files and display it in a DataGridView.

Is there a way to merge the data from multiple files into a single DataSet?

Alternately can I write linq to dataset queries across multiple DataSets?

Comment: Same question, earlier today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869022/query-a-dataset

Comment: No it's not.  That was in regards to the contents of a single dataset.  I'm now asking how to combine data from multiple datasets.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate of the earlier question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the [DataSet.Merge()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/803bh6bc.aspx) method will help you out?  You can simply load the files as you're currently doing, and merge them together.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding the MSDN documentation that's for combining stuff with the same schema, not for packing two sets with different schemas into the same container.

Comment: Dan, the DataSet.Merge() is used  to merge two DataSet objects that have largely similar schemas. I think your way out of this problem is to build your own tool that understands both schemas and build in the proper rules for merging those.